# Firebase read data inside data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

In my Kotlin app, I have Firebase with a set of loop objects inside the value. How do I read the values of each in?

```
user -> history -> location
```

[image]

```html
 for (childsnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
     val name = childsnapshot.key

     val locList: Map<String, Any> = childsnapshot.value as Map<String, Any>
     val val_obj = JSONObject(locList) as JSONObject
                   
     val pin_image = val_obj.get("image").toString()

    val history_location = val_obj.getJSONObject("history").getJSONObject("location")
    
    var i =0;
    while(i<history_location.length()){
         
     i++
    }               

}
```

I want to run a loop to read the list of `location` inside history..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `lastCheckedDate` property, for Java users please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference locationRef = rootRef.child("Qwerr").child("history").child("location");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String lastCheckedDate = ds.child("lastCheckedDate").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", lastCheckedDate);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
locationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

And for Kotlin users:

```
val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener() {
    fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            val lastCheckedDate: String = ds.child("lastCheckedDate").getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", lastCheckedDate)
        }
    }

    fun onCancelled(@NonNull databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
locationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
2020/09/14 13:20:51
2020/09/14 13:21:49
...
```

If you need to get the data under `latlng` node, then you should go one step deeper in your database tree and add a `.child("latlng")` call.

---

**Edit:**

To get the value of the `latitude` and `longitude` properties that exist under the `latlng` node, please use this code:

```
val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener() {
    fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            val latitude: Long = ds.child("latlng").child("latitude").getValue(Long::class.java)
            val longitude: Long = ds.child("latlng").child("longitude").getValue(Long::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", latitude + ", " + longitude)
        }
    }

    fun onCancelled(@NonNull databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
locationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: I want to read all values inside "Qwrr" user , I can read the direct values , but i dont know how to read the values inisde history -> location

Comment: As I already said in my answer, add a .child("latlng") call. If you have a hard time getting that data, please edit your question and add the latlng structure as a screenshot.

Comment: THis is my entire data snapshot for the user "Qwerr"
                    val locList: Map<String, Any> = dataSnapshot.value as Map<String, Any>
                    val val_obj = JSONObject(locList) as JSONObject
                    val image = val_obj.getJSONObject("image")

                    val history_location =
                        val_obj.getJSONObject("history").getJSONObject("location")


hisory -> location has a seperate key value pair.. I'm not sure how to read from this point..

Comment: There is no need for a `JSONObject`. As I already asked you, please edit your question and add the latlng structure as a screenshot.

Comment: As I already asked you twice, please edit your question and add the latlng structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I need to write in loop to access all items.. but it is showing error

Comment: @GK_ Add a screenshot that contains the content of `latlng` in the database. It's the third time I'm asking you the same thing.

Comment: Please visit my original question above, It contains the structure of my DB screenshot. 

I have "history -> location -> (Key) -> latlng & lastCheckedDate" .. I hope you get it.. 

It will be added dynamically in the history, when the user changes location.

Comment: I totally understand you but that `latlng` is an object that has some data inside. The screenshot is not complete. There is a `+` sign there, click it and show me what is inside. Are there two properties, `latitude` and `longitude`? Or `lat` and `lng`?

Comment: Updated the Screenshot in the original question above

Comment: @GK_ This is what I was asking for, so thanks. Please also check my updated answer. Is it working now?

Comment: if you see inside the main loop, i fetch the history -> location as object 

"val history_location = val_obj.getJSONObject("history").getJSONObject("location")" 

   How do i make it as loop and read the "latlng"  inside it ?

Comment: This is **not** how you should do it. Have you tried the code I have provided in my updated answer? Does it work?

Comment: I have to read the entire user info at one shot.. I dont want to call firebase instance again to get the datasnapshot

Comment: There is no problem in calling instance again, it's a Singleton. You'll always use a single object. Is it ok now?

Comment: So there is no way, I can read the objects from here itself ? or should i change the structure to better way?

Comment: You can read all objects using this database schema, either by using the first approach or using the second. Can I help you with other information?